# Hausman test from Wooldridge (adding level variables)

Tags: econometrics

Wooldridge's graduate textbook (p.285) says that:

> We can formally test the assumptions underlying the consistency of the FE and FD estimators by using a Hausman test. [...] If T = 2, it is easy to test for strict exogeneity. In the equation $\Delta y_i = \Delta x_i \beta + \Delta u_i $, **neither $x_{i1}$ nor $x_{i2}$ should be significant as additional explanatory variables in the first-differenced equation**.

Why is this? The strict exogeneity condition for FD is in differences, not levels: $E[\Delta x \Delta u]=0$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the idea is a little heuristic of Wooldridge.
If the model is specified correctly (strict exogeneity is true), then $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ should only be predictive of $\Delta y_i$ through $\Delta x_i$. The test is to evaluate if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that makes sense. So it is simply a question of whether the model is dynamically complete.